# What process executes rpc:cast?

Tags: concurrency, erlang

Right now I am building a distributed application and am looking into using rpc:cast vs rpc:call because I don't want the calling processes to wait on the return value, or even receive one.

Cast works perfectly for this, but I am curious, what process executes the function passed by rpc:cast and call? Should I be worried about over/under concurrency?

Usually, when I want another process executing code, I use a pool of workers and send one of them an asynchronous cast with gen_server:cast/2 and let them handle it. But for RPC, it doesn't define what process does the computation. Are the processes pre-allocated and waiting? Or is every process spawned as rpc calls it and then terminated? From what I have read, this is incredibly inefficient if you are making many calls, as the processes are just being created and destroyed which isn't computationally easy.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

A process spawned on the target node to handle the RPC.

**Discussion**

If we take a look at the code for the rpc module, we see that it wraps the underlying normal inter-node messaging features in disterl:

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/rpc.erl#L398-L403

```
-spec cast(Node, Module, Function, Args) -> true when
      Node :: node(),
      Module :: module(),
      Function :: atom(),
      Args :: [term()].

cast(Node, Mod, Fun, Args) when Node =:= node() ->
    catch spawn(Mod, Fun, Args),
    true;
cast(Node, Mod, Fun, Args) ->
    gen_server:cast({?NAME,Node}, {cast,Mod,Fun,Args,group_leader()}),
    true.
```

What is happening there is that when cast is called on the current node, a *new process* is spawned with the provided MFA to be executed. If case is being called on a different node, then a message is sent via `gen_server:cast/2` to the indicated node's group leader, and the group leader on the target node will spawn a process to handle the MFA.

The handling code for the cast is here:

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/rpc.erl#L130-L139

```
-spec handle_cast(term(), state()) -> {'noreply', state()}.

handle_cast({cast, Mod, Fun, Args, Gleader}, S) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
          set_group_leader(Gleader),
          apply(Mod, Fun, Args)
      end),
    {noreply, S};
handle_cast(_, S) ->
    {noreply, S}. % Ignore !
```

In the case that you *already know* which process you want to dispatch a message to on the other node, then it would possibly make more sense to treat the mesh of nodes as a supernode, bypass the rpc module entirely and just make a gen_server call or cast directly to it. Which approach to use is a matter of taste and architecture, of course.

Comment: So it is probably not a good idea to be sending tons of rpc communication because each time node1 receives an rpc from node2, it has to spawn off a whole new process, which I have read is intensive.

Comment: You suggest an alternative, to get predefined information about the node and send it a gen_server:cast() -  Ideally though you would want to use a pool so that 1) no new processes are spawned(time concern) 2) if an influx of messages come, then concurrency is limited. How then would you know the process id, if to get a process id you have to first consult some form of grpoc_get_worker on node1 from node2? Is there any commonly accepted workaround to this or is it sort of a "fix" that everyone does differently?

Comment: @Ryan Actually, I have good news for you! Spawning processes in Erlang is *extremely lightweight* in time, memory and CPU. The network communication and latency involved in talking to another node is much more expensive than the job `rex` is doing. So even though there is only one `rex` on the other side you could probably spam it pretty hard with requests without too much worry -- the overhead of `rex`'s work is negligible. If you have significantly complex calculations where RPC is a good fit then the cost of the cast is the least of your overhead concerns.

Comment: @Ryan As for "an alternative", you can spawn a process on another node directly, which is why `spawn/2` and `spawn/4` accept a `Node` argument (http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-2). All of this is impossible to make good judgements on without knowing what the jobs are, what the load looks like, etc. Context of operation is everything. Whatever it is you're doing, writing some test cases to see how they react to your load should be pretty straightforward. You could come to [Erlang/OTP chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp) to discuss it with us.

Comment: Thanks so much. You can tell i had concerns about all these processes but it doesn't seem like it will be a big deal. I don't remember where I read that processes had a high overhead in erlang, but I'm happy now knowing that it's not a big concern. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the process is `rex`. It is a registered process which spawns a process which executes `apply(M, F, A)`.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/rpc.erl#L28

and

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/rpc.erl#L402

BTW, it means all `rpc:call/4` and `rpc:cast/4` and others parameters go through one process which limits scalability. `rpc` module is not intended for a high throughput purposes.

Comment: They pas through `rex`, but `rex` spawns a separate worker to actually execute each job unless it is sent a `call_block` (which then `rex` executes own its own).

Comment: Yep, you are right. `rex` spawns a process which does real work. I edit the answer.

Comment: Because spawning is so fast in Erlang, I think the big performance bottleneck surprise would be the difference people will encounter over disterl between sending large and small messages. If the arguments to the rpc call were huge in terms of bytes you could start getting strange behavior. Or if the connection was slow or high latency. RPC gets complex pretty quick, but I think the spawning part is the smallest of all overheads here (on the order of 8 microseconds or so, network latency is going to be *way* higher than this usually).